# Access @property from ^block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am getting an (lldb) error when I try to make changes to a @property I declared in my StreamScreen UIViewController class.

I am making trying to change the feedList object in the asyncRequest success block. The asyncRequest method is a class method that I imported and is part of my class called NSURLConnection-block.

**So...**

I am trying to change an NSMutableArray (feedList) which is part of StreamScreen inside a block in StreamScreen and that block is called by a class method (asyncRequest) from another class but I am getting an error.

In the Debug Navigator I get - `error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file`

**Here is some of my code...**

**This is where I declare the feedList @property (StreamScreen.h)**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *feedList;
```

**The code below is the getStream method with the asyncRequest class method in  (StreamScreen.m)**

```
- (void)getStream {
    NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://198.199.71.169/getFB.php?at=%@", fbAccessToken];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection asyncRequest:request
                          success:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response) {
                              NSLog(@"%@", feedList);
                          }
                          failure:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error! %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                          }];
}
```

I instantiate the feedList NSMutableArray and call the getStream method in my viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    feedList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"zero", @"one", @"two", nil];
    [self getStream];    
}
```

***EDIT:***

**Here is NSURLConnection-block.m**

```
#import "NSURLConnection-block.h"

@implementation NSURLConnection (block)

#pragma mark API
+ (void)asyncRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request success:(void(^)(NSData *,NSURLResponse *))successBlock_ failure:(void(^)(NSData *,NSError *))failureBlock_
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backgroundSync:) toTarget:[NSURLConnection class]
                           withObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       request,@"request",
                                       successBlock_,@"success",
                                       failureBlock_,@"failure",
                                       nil]];
}

#pragma mark Private
+ (void)backgroundSync:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    //NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    void(^success)(NSData *,NSURLResponse *) = [dictionary objectForKey:@"success"];
    void(^failure)(NSData *,NSError *) = [dictionary objectForKey:@"failure"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [dictionary objectForKey:@"request"];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        failure(data,error);
    }
    else
    {
        success(data,response);
    }
    //[pool release];
}


@end
```

**Here is NSURLConnection-block.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSURLConnection (block)
#pragma mark Class API Extensions
+ (void)asyncRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request success:(void(^)(NSData *,NSURLResponse *))successBlock_ failure:(void(^)(NSData *,NSError *))failureBlock_;
@end
```

I hope someone can help me. I'd really appreciate it! :)

Comment: What's the text of the error you're getting?

Comment: In the console... `(lldb)`

Comment: In the Debug Navigator... `error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file`

Comment: this is a runtime, not a compiler, error?

Comment: Yes @bshirley it is a runtime error.

Comment: The code you've provided is not wrong. Given that so far you're not actually doing anything with the received data I copied the code but used Google for the URL - works fine, as it should. Your bad access error suggests that something has gone awry with the block's storage. Use the debugger and breakpoint in your blocks. What values do you see for `feedList`? Does it look like a valid address? Is it the same address as in the property (print it out using %p format in NSLog)? Etc. HTH.

Comment: If I NSLog `feedList` in the `getStream` method (just above the start of the block then I get it's contents, but if I NSLog it inside the block, I get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Comment: @JacquesBlom Use the debugger not NSLog (or at least use NSLog's %p format to show the address value). What you're seeing suggests a bad value, you need to see that value and try to figure out its origin.

Comment: I can't access any synthesized property inside the block. Could it be because the block is called by another class?

Comment: @JacquesBlom - Invoking a block in a class other than the one in which it was created is not your problem *per se*. Think about it, how useful would blocks be if that was a restriction? No system APIs could take blocks... Recall above, *I have essentially run your code* and it works (differences, I used Google and <https://github.com/rickerbh/NSURLConnection-Blocks> - neither should be an issue). Without further details, e.g. what exactly does the debugger show you, anybody trying to help will probably be guessing. Unfortunately SO probably isn't the place to get help debugging at this level.

Comment: @JacquesBlom - Invoking a block in a class other than the one in which it was created is not your problem *per se*. Think about it, how useful would blocks be if that was a restriction? No system APIs could take blocks... Recall above, *I have essentially run your code* and it works (differences, I used Google and <https://github.com/rickerbh/NSURLConnection-Blocks> - neither should be an issue). Without further details, e.g. what exactly does the debugger show you, anybody trying to help will probably be guessing. Unfortunately SO probably isn't the place to get help debugging at this level.

Answer (score 1):

Are you synthesizing `feedList` to a `feedList` ivar yourself? Otherwise try `_feedList`, which is the default synthesized variable.

Comment: I have `@synthesize feedTableView, feedList;`

Answer (score 0):

You might not get what you expect if the compiler didn't complain.  You are freezing the value of `feedList` at the time you are making the `asyncRequest`.

Try

```
[self feedList]
```

or perhaps, more usefully, `response` which is obviously in scope in the block

Comment: on which change? `[self feedList]` or `response`?

Comment: If I do add this - `NSLog(@"%@", [self feedList]);` - it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the error occurs due to the multi-thread environment:

What happens, when you put this in the success block?:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.feedList);
});
```

Comment: Error is on the `void(^success)(NSData *,NSURLResponse *) = [dictionary objectForKey:@"success"];` line of NSURLConnection-block.m.

Comment: I simulated your code. (UIViewController instead of NSURLConnection+Block, with this three method and the property). Used `self.feedlist` in viewDidLoad, and `@""` as fbAccessToken, because i didn't wanted to link FB SDK. I narrowed down the problem to the NSDictionary creation part, and replaced it with the new synthax `@{"key" : object}` and i don't get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (before that i got, exactly where you pointed it out). So try `@{
        @"request":request,
        @"success":successBlock_,
        @"failure":failureBlock_
    }`